# Cannot render array elements using map in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have below `react-native` code that I am using to render a text of array elements using `map`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {Card} from 'react-native-elements';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';


class Contact extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            arr:["Vipul","Satish","Manisha","Jonty"]
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <Card>
                <Card.Title>Contact Information</Card.Title>
                <Card.Divider />
                <View>
                    {
                        this.state.arr.map(function(elem){
                            console.log(elem)
                            return(
                                <Text>Hello {elem}</Text>
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </View>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}

export default Contact;
```

I already have array setup with state in constructor of my class. First I was using arrow function to return `<Text>`. But it wasn't working. Now regular function isn't working too.
I am getting below error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

However, If I replace my render function with this:

```
render(){
   return(<View><Text>Hello world</Text></View>);
}
```

then everything is working fine and I am getting Hello world on screen. Also, the `console.log` in the above code is correctly printing all the array elements but it is just that the elements are not being rendered.

I have checked other topics similar to this but couldn't get any help.

Thank You!
The state is this:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            arr:["Vipul","Satish","Manisha","Jonty"]
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**:
This is what has been given on their official website:

```
<Card>
  <Card.Title>CARD WITH DIVIDER</Card.Title>
  <Card.Divider/>
  {
    users.map((u, i) => {
      return (
        <View key={i} style={styles.user}>
          <Image
            style={styles.image}
            resizeMode="cover"
            source={{ uri: u.avatar }}
          />
          <Text style={styles.name}>{u.name}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    })
  }
</Card>
```

You can see that my code is just similar to this one, so it should work that way.

Comment: I am 99% sure that the problem is in your state structure. Please, post it here.

Comment: Had it been a problem with state, the console.log wouldn't have printed elements.

Comment: The state does seem correct. Can you please post `<Card />`? I see that you render `Card`, and then `Card.Divider`, `Card.Title` etc. How could that be?

Comment: I saw that on their official website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what lib you are using for `Card` but it may take a `title` prop not a string as a child.

Comment: I am using ``react-native-elements`` for Card

Comment: are you showing all the code? i suspect the issue is somewhere not being shown

Comment: I must say that the problem lies in the map itself because as I said, if I remove everything from render and just return hello world, it is working fine.

Comment: see the official docs of react-native card:https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/card/

Comment: the code runs fine in an expo snack, perhaps you need to update react-native-elements to latest or post the full error message in which there is an error somewhere else in your project

Comment: It is kinda weird. What I am pretty sure is that the error has nothing to do with a card.

Comment: After scratching my head for an hour, I have found that the problem lies in ``<Card.Title>``. I think it should take title as a prop.

Comment: @VIPULTYAGI not sure what version of react native elements lib you are using but it seems working fine. https://snack.expo.io/@iamakash/react-native-card-view?&iframeId=3wygkzm0hq&preview=true&platform=ios&theme=dark
The only difference is that you are using a class component, I am using a functional component with hooks